# Postgis: find geometry within multiple polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I've got two tables with geometry in it.
Table 1:`items` holds items with a point geometry; while the second table `property_zones` holds polygons.

**The Items:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.items
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('item_id_seq'::regclass),
  ....
  geom geometry(Point,4326),
  ....
)
```

**The zones**

```
CREATE TABLE public.property_zones
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('property_zones_id_seq'::regclass),
  prop_id integer NOT NULL,
  ....
  geom geometry(Polygon,4326)
)
```

Both tables have GIST indexes on the geom column.

I now want to query these tables and find every item within the zones op a particular property (denoted with `prop_id`). I came up with this SQL, which works but has a flaw in it:

```
SELECT i.id
FROM items AS i
WHERE 
   ST_Within(i.geom ,
               ( SELECT geom FROM property_zones WHERE prop_id = :propid )
             )
```

This works perfectly, but some properties have multiple zones, and off course the query within the ST_Within delivers more than 1 tuple. And of course I can return to a php solution where I split the query up in a couple of query's; but I really want a query based solution. (If possible)

How can I rewrite this code to find every item within the zones (1 or more) of each property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The subquery is completely unnecessary. Flatten the query:

```
SELECT i.id
FROM
  items AS i,
  property_zones AS z
WHERE prop_id = :propid AND ST_Within(i.geom, z.geom)
```

You could also rewrite this using a [JOIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html):

```
SELECT i.id
FROM items AS i
JOIN property_zones AS z ON prop_id = :propid AND ST_Within(i.geom, z.geom)
```

Be sure to also have an index on `prop_id`.

Comment: Thank you! I followed an tutorial from boundless where they put the geometry to compare directly in the ST_Within Forgot that it is just a column which can be joined/from... Is there any significant speed difference between the join and the first?

Comment: I recall that they are similar in efficiency, but check the query planner. Joins can make things tidyer when more than two tables are joined together, so I normally prefer this style.